Prove that $\sum {\frac{(2n)!}{4^{n} \cdot n (n!)^{2}}}$ Converges
Wolfram alpha says that the summation converges to $ln(4)$.
I have tried ratio test and root test, both being inconclusive, since limits are coming out to be 1.
